# DFS algorithm is searching from right to left

Tags: java, search, tree, depth-first-search

I have written a Depth First Search algorithm, but it is searching from the right side of the tree towards the left. I can see from my code why it is doing so, but I cannot come up with a solution to change it so that it searches from left to right.

```
public class DFS {

    public LinkedList<Node> search(Node root, Node target) {    
        LinkedList<Node> open = new LinkedList<>();
        LinkedList<Node> closed = new LinkedList<>();

        open.addLast(root);
        while (!open.isEmpty()) {
            Node current = open.removeFirst();
            if (current.equals(target)) {
                closed.addLast(current);
                return closed;
            }
            else {
                ArrayList<Node> children = current.getChildren();
                closed.addLast(current);
                for (Node child : children) {
                    if (!open.contains(child) && !closed.contains(child)) {
                        open.addFirst(child);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

`closed` is a list of the nodes visited in the order in which they were visited.

`Node.getChildren()` returns an ArrayList of the node's children in the order in which they were added.

**EDIT**

Here is the node class:

```
public class Node {

    private ArrayList<Node> children;
    private String name;

    public Node(String name){
        children = new ArrayList<Node>();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ArrayList<Node> getChildren(){
        return new ArrayList<Node>(children);
    }

    public Node addChild(Node child){
        children.add(child);
        return child;
    }

    public void removeChild(Node child){
        children.remove(child);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public boolean equals(Node other){
        return (this.getName().compareTo(other.getName())==0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing `children.remove(child)`, especially during a loop over `children`?

Comment: Since you pointed that out, I don't know what purpose it serves! Basically I just wanted to discard that node. I will edit my code now

Comment: @user2357112 Fixed.

Comment: I'm a bit confused: title mention DepthFS, the class is name BFS. Which one is the typo? Just to make sure, do you want Depth First or Breadth First? At a cursory examination of your code, I'm not seeing any `pop` from the `closed` which is unusual for a DFS - certainly you will have branches which will fail to get an answer an need to be discarded.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi my bad, when I edited my question a few minutes I go, I think I copied and pasted my BFS algorithm instead. I have fixed it now. `closed` returns a correct DFS search pattern, but it travels down the right-hand side of the tree when it can, instead of the left

Comment: Your Nodes... do they make a Tree, DAG or a Graph? (should one expect cycles? Should one expect double-visiting a Node?)

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi It is a Binary Tree. I have added my `Node` class too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple response to 'how to avoid right-to-left' question is:

```
            ArrayList<Node> children = current.getChildren();
            closed.addLast(current);
            // *** Not like this ***
            // for (Node child : children) {
            //    if (!open.contains(child) && !closed.contains(child)) {
            //        open.addFirst(child);
            //    }
            //}
            // **** But like this ****
            for(int i=children.size()-1; i>=0; i-- ) {
                Node child=children.get(i);
                if (!open.contains(child) && !closed.contains(child)) {
                    open.addFirst(child);
                }
            }
            // If you are **absolutely** sure your structure is a 
            // Tree (thus, no cycles) then testing against 
            // open/closed is unnecessary and the code can be simplified: as
            // open.addAll(0, children);
```

You algo is flawed anyway: there's no provision to windup/discard a descending path in the tree that failed to bear a result (you never remove from `closed`) - but this is out of the scope of your question.

Comment: This worked perfectly and I also now understand why by writing out a test case on paper. Thank you.

The algorithm was given to us as pseudocode and the assignment asks to write a test class which states whether a path can be found to the target node or not - I presume as protection for what you pointed out. We have just begun with these search algorithms and so were probably made as simple as possible in this case.

Comment: While my answer works from the point of view of "visiting order", be aware that you `closed` list does **not** contain the descending path from the root, but *all the nodes you visited until you found the answer - including the failing branches*. If the assignment requires you to return the actual "path from root", you still have work to do.

Comment: I was aware of that, but the extent of the assignment asks to print all nodes that were visited prior to the target node. Thank you for the help

Comment: Ah, Ok, the trace-of-the-search. In this case, it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

If your DFS really relies on the direction, reverse your children, or addFirst instead of addLast?

Answer (score 0):

getChildren has elements 1..n

Then you have a stack "open", from which you pop the first element every time you execute the main loop.

You fill this stack by pushing childs to the front of the stack (`addFirst`), then for 1..n you end with n..1 (insert 1, it is now first, insert 2, it is now first, 1 is second, and so on).

pop open from the last index, or push children to the end of the stack and it should work unless getChildren is not returning in the order you claim it does.

Comment: Before writing this DFS algorithm, I wrote a BFS one in which the only difference was the solution you proposed. Popping from the last index creates a BFS algorithm. I have tested `getChildren()` and it does return the list in the correct order.

Comment: yeah you kept editing your question and the code would change ordering every time